# Image transform in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, transform, imagemagick-convert, gdlib

to keep it simple I am trying to put a image on a image/canvas.
Canvas = 1920x1080, image size doesn't matter.
I want to add the image into the canvas but with specific x/y coordination for each corner.
Look at my array here below to see what I'm working with:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [cp1x] => 500
    [cp1y] => 250
    [cp2x] => 250
    [cp2y] => 380
    [cp3x] => 400
    [cp3y] => 700
    [cp4x] => 1500
    [cp4y] => 800
)
```

CP1X/CP1Y are for the top left.
CP2X/CP2Y are for the top right.
CP3X/CP3Y are for the lower left.
CP4X/CP4Y are for the lower right.

I'd preferably get a solution in php and -or ImageMagick.

Also made sketches to give a better explanation.
Hope it's all clear.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQN91.png)

[Base/canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owRBt.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoKwi.png)

Tried making it with Imagick and PHP transform.

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinates do not match your description. They are list counter clockwise from the top left.

You can get the result in Imagemagick using +distort perspective between your coordinates and the corners of the input images.

Input:

[image]

Unix syntax:

```
canvas_size="1920x1080"
canvas_color="blue"
# points listed counter clockwise from top left
cp1x=500
cp1y=250
cp2x=250
cp2y=380
cp3x=400
cp3y=700
cp4x=1500
cp4y=800
infile="lena.png"
ww=`convert "$infile" -format "%w" info:`
hh=`convert "$infile" -format "%h" info:`
p1x=0
p1y=0
p2x=0
p2y=$((hh-1))
p3x=$((ww-1))
p3y=$((hh-1))
p4x=$((ww-1))
p4y=0
convert \( -size $canvas_size xc:"$canvas_color" \) \
\( "$infile" -virtual-pixel none -mattecolor none -define distort:viewport=${canvas_size}+0+0 +distort perspective \
"$p1x,$p1y $cp1x,$cp1y  $p2x,$p2y $cp2x,$cp2y  $p3x,$p3y $cp3x,$cp3y  $p4x,$p4y $cp4x,$cp4y" \) \
-compose over -composite \
result.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any working PHP setup, but here's how you do it on the command line. I used a 1920x1080 swirl as the background (`bg.jpg`) with your 400x400 overlay image as the foreground (`fg.jpg`) to distort:

[image]

```
magick bg.jpg \
   \( fg.png -virtual-pixel transparent +distort Perspective '0,0,500,250 399,0 1500,380 0,399,400,800 399,399,1250,700' \) \
   -flatten result.png
```

[image]

You will see there are 4 pairs of coordinates, with those in the source image listed before the corresponding point in the destination image.